# Network.Socket not exporting all functions and constants

Tags: haskell

I am following https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server. I have written up to https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server#Simple_socket_server, but only some of the functions and constants seem to be exported. All of the functions and constants referenced seem to exist as I expect apart from `iADDR_ANY` and `send`. Replacing `iADDR_ANY` with the result from `inet_addr` just shows inet_addr is undefined as well.

I am using stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the tutorial uses an older version of network. The functions it uses were removed in 3.0.0.0 (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.0.1.0/changelog). Solution is to rewrite using new functions.